# Ruby on rails active record multiple group record to calculate numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to calculate number of employee who has commanded to shoot on every day.

```
   Shoot.where("command_type = ?", "shoot").group("DATE(created_at)").group("employee_number").order("DATE(created_at)").count
```

It will give me a output like

```
   {[Wed, 03 Aug 2011, "7838744451"]=>2, [Wed, 03 Aug 2011, "8055898284"]=>11,[Fri, 05 Aug 2011, "9702553828"]=>1, [Fri, 05 Aug 2011, "9717466677"]=>1,[Fri, 05 Aug 2011, "8055898284"]=>1,[Wed, 06 Aug 2011, "8055898284"]=>5
```

I want to have an array something like:-

```
 [2,0,3,1]  // zero is for the dates when no record is there for that date. and number in the array is that number of the employees that has been ordered to shoot.
```

For example from array: 2 employee were ordered to shoot on Wed, 3rd. 
 0 employee were ordered to shoot on 4th and so on...

Also: How can i calculate that a how many times all employees were commanded to shoot in a week/month. Basically 100 employee were ordered to shoot 1st week. 120 employees were order to shoot 2nd week and so on 1st month and 2nd month..

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project...

Comment: who downvoted me? Can any1 tell me whats the issue. Is this a bad question or this is bad way to ask question.. please leave a comment.

Comment: @sscrirrus project in the sense?

Comment: nothing, just kidding :) Talking about how many employees are 'shooting' it sounds like something out of Blackwater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using returns the daily count by employee. If you want to get the daily count across employees, remove the 2nd `group` call.

```
# return [2,3,1]
Shoot.where(:command_type => shoot").group("DATE(created_at)").values
```

If you want to fill the missing date values, you can use this function:

```
class Shoot
  def self.daily_count_by_type(type = "shoot", range=7.days)
    counts = Shoot.where(:command_type => type).group("DATE(created_at)").
               count("DISTINCT employee_id")
    (range.ago.to_date..Date.today).map {|d| counts[d.to_s] || 0}
  end
end
```

Now

```
Shoot.daily_count_by_type # for type `shoot`, last 7 days
Shoot.daily_count_by_type("shoot") # for type `shoot`, last 7 days
Shoot.daily_count_by_type("eat", 14.days) # for type `eat`, last 14 days
Shoot.daily_count_by_type("leave") # for type `leave`, last 14 days
```

Make sure you add an index on `DATE(CREATED_AT)` to improve the performance.

**Edit 1**

Based on the comment you need to COUNT the distinct values. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thing is One employee can be ordered to shoot twice or thrice on the same day. So I want to count it as one.

Comment: Based on the comment you need to COUNT the distinct values. I have updated the answer accordingly.